# Returning methods on windows forms app

Tags: c#, winforms

Windows forms newbie here, just have a simple question regarding numeric up-down tool.

I have created a program that calculates the cost for car rentals based on size, insurance and discounts. The calculations work fine, however the up-down seems to be "stuck" and shows the values for each day of rental one day behind. For example, if a small size car is $60 per day, and I change the numeric up-down to 2 days, it will show the correct price when 3 days are selected.

Any suggestions on where I've gone wrong would be appreciated.

Code below:

---

```
namespace ica3_eventdriven
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const double smallRate = 40.00;
        const double midRate = 50.00;
        const double sportRate = 60.00;
        const double insurance = 15.00;
        const double AMA_Discount = 0.1;
        int days;
        double total;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void tbxName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            enableControls();
        }

        private void enableControls()
        {
            if(tbxName.Text != String.Empty)
            {
                rbSmall.Enabled = true;
                rbMid.Enabled = true;
                rbSports.Enabled = true;
                cbxInsurance.Enabled = true;
                cbxAMA.Enabled = true;
                ctrDays.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void rbSmall_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculate();
        }

        private void Calculate()
        {
            int.TryParse(ctrDays.Text, out days);


            if (rbSmall.Checked)
            {
                total = smallRate * days;
                labelTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");

                if(cbxInsurance.Checked)
                {
                    total = (smallRate * days) + (insurance * days);
                    labelTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");
                }

                if(cbxAMA.Checked)
                {
                    total = 0.9 * (smallRate * days);
                    labelTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");
                }

                if(cbxInsurance.Checked && cbxAMA.Checked)
                {
                    total = 0.9 * ((smallRate * days) + (insurance * days));
                    labelTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");
                }
            }

            if (rbMid.Checked)
            {
                total = midRate * days;
                labelTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");

                if (cbxInsurance.Checked)
                {
                    total = (midRate * days) + (insurance * days);
                    labelTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");
                }

                if (cbxAMA.Checked)
                {
                    total = 0.9 * (midRate * days);
                    labelTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");
                }

                if (cbxInsurance.Checked && cbxAMA.Checked)
                {
                    total = 0.9 * ((midRate * days) + (insurance * days));
                    labelTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");
                }
            }

            if (rbSports.Checked)
            {
                total = sportRate * days;
                labelTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");

                if (cbxInsurance.Checked)
                {
                    total = (sportRate * days) + (insurance * days);
                    labelTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");
                }

                if (cbxAMA.Checked)
                {
                    total = 0.9 * (sportRate * days);
                    labelTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");
                }

                if (cbxInsurance.Checked && cbxAMA.Checked)
                {
                    total = 0.9 * ((sportRate * days) + (insurance * days));
                    labelTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");
                }
            }

        }

        private void ctrDays_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculate();
        }

        private void cbxInsurance_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculate();
        }

        private void cbxAMA_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculate();
        }

        private void rbMid_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculate();
        }

        private void rbSports_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint and step through your code to debug it.

Comment: Is the days has correct value. Have you debugged it. Are all values as expected. or where which value is not correct.

Comment: As the others have stated above you should debug your code and look for unexpected values, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243867.aspx.

Comment: By analysing your code it seams that if `rbSmall`, `rbMid`, and `rbSports` are all unchecked, the label won't change value. I suggest add a case when nothing is checked to empty the output label value so that it is obvious on the GUI that this is the case.